# Visual Studio, Linq-to-Sql, designer settings?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq-to-sql

Is there some place I can change output settings for the Visual Studio Linq-to-Sql designer? I would like to control if table names are pluralized/depluralized, add specific attributes, namespace etc. Can something of this be done without manually changing the files after they are created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems at this point the answer is "no".

Answer (score 1):

You can change the names of tables/entities from the Table properties in the designer. It has a Name, and a Source. The Source, of course, is the underlying database, but you can change the name to suit your needs. Other than that, I don't know of a way to specifically pluralize or depluralize items.

Also, don't manually edit the files output by the L2S designer - they'll just get overwritten the next time you make a change in the designer. To extend the generated classes, use partial classes.

Comment: Thanks! I'm aware of partial classes. But your first suggestion, how is that different from changing the actual designer file? Isn't that just the same? So this will be overwritten when updated. My question is if it exists any settings that impacts the way the designer actually creates the classes.

Comment: Ah, I guess I misunderstood your question. I don't think there is any way to control that. You can control the namespace from the properties window, but not the pluralization. If you want that type of flexibility/configurability, you'll probably have to move to Entity Framework.